# Unity - Can't center mini-map viewport rect inside center of the image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**How do I convert image position to camera viewport view?**

I have a radar and I use a camera to show that viewport on the screen but it only works on a set rect which works fine for only 1 type of screen, the one that i set.

How can I match this rect to a image transform position. so if the screen changes and as it moves, the ui around it will move the camera view with it too.

This is for the screen of an iPhone XS Max (2688x1242)

I would want something like overlayCamera.rect = transform.position

Here is the code that I use to show the camera rect.

```
private void UpdateCameraViewportRect()
{
    float aspectRatio = (float)Screen.width / Screen.height;
    float desiredScreenWidth = 0.271f;
    float viewHeight = 0.831f;
    float viewWidth = 0.78f;

    float width = desiredScreenWidth;
    float height = width * aspectRatio;
    if (height > 1.0f)
    {
        height = 1.0f;
        width = height / aspectRatio;
    }
    
    //  Controls the position of the view
    overlayCamera.rect = new Rect(
        viewHeight - width, viewWidth - height,
        width, height
    );
    
    /*
    // Method 1 -> Does not work
    Vector3 p = overlayCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, overlayCamera.nearClipPlane));
    Debug.Log(p);

    // Method 2 -> Does not work
    Vector3 screenPos = overlayCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(overlayCamera.transform.position);
    float posx = screenPos.x - (width * 0.5f);
    float posy = screenPos.y - (height * 0.5f);
    Debug.Log(posx + " & " + posy);

    // Method 3 -> Does not work
    overlayCamera.rect = radarBorder.rectTransform.rect;
    */
}
```

How can I center the viewport rect in the center of the gold border image?

Solution: Create a RenderTexture instead and show it in a RawImage to move around the UI.

Comment: I'd like to help but don't quite understand what you are trying to do, perhaps adding some screenshots or diagrams would help.

Comment: @PeterHayman For my UI I have a UI image of a border. I would like to put the camera viewport rect inside the UI image. The camera viewport of the minimap divides the viewport view of the screen by the width and height. I would like to change that positioning to the center of the UI image position. How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry that didn't help, screenshots please.

Comment: @PeterHayman sorry I added an image, see how the viewport rect is not center inside the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I may have misunderstood but it looks like the approach is to adjust the UI dynamically based on the aspect ratio of the screen.

It may be best to lay out the UI normally in the editor and force the aspect ratio of the overlayCamera to be 1:1 using [Camera.aspect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html):

```
void Start(){
    var cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    cam.aspect = 1;
    cam.ResetAspect();
}
```

EDIT:

While it is possible to adjust where on the screen a camera renders, as you can see its a little messy. Common practice is to [render to a RenderTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html) and place that on a material inside the UI.

Comment: thank you but I would like the opposite, I would like to adjust the cameras viewport rect to be centered inside an image.

Comment: where can I find some examples of RenderTexture? sounds like a perfect idea.

Comment: The RenderTexture was exactly what I wanted. Thank you!